# how to write data on existing xls or xlsx file using apache POI in android

Tags: java, android, apache, apache-poi, xls

i try to put data in a template .xls file (it can be xlsx if necessary) using apache POI but i can't figure it out and the file is still unchanged . no exception thrown in PrintStackTrace . would you please provide me with a working code? i read so many documents so please help me with working code. thanks

my code :

```
 final Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bk);
        but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


                try {

                    writeXLSFile(3, 3);


                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });

public static void writeXLSFile(int row, int col) throws IOException {
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"telegran/"+ "ex.xls");

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Cell cell = null;

        //Update the value of cell

        cell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(col);
        cell.setCellValue("changed");

        file.close();

        FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"telegran/"+ "ex.xls"));
        workbook.write(outFile);
        outFile.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try to  file.close(); after  workbook.write(outFile);  outFile.close();

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is you are trying to get a row and a cell that were not created in the first place.
You need to create a `Row` first before calling `cell = sheet.getRow(row);` like

`XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex);`

And create a `Cell` as well like

```
Cell cell = row.createCell(cellIndex);
```

see this [full example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/apache_poi_spreadsheets.htm)  for more details

Comment: cell 3,3 is already created and has a value. thank you anyway but dont have any other idea?

Comment: Have you tried XSSF instead? I've used apache poi only once and the example I've given the link to works just fine.

Comment: yes i did and all the same :(
there was an edited apache poi on github optimized for android but it was much worse ,
have you ever heard any app used apache poi to edit an existing excel file?

Comment: Okay this may sound silly but i think you missed a "/" before "telegran" FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"telegran/"+ "ex.xls"));  should be "/telegran/"+"ex.xls"